# Check if combobox value is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have created a ComboBox with three values. I wanted that a message box opens when no item is selected so I tried this:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a value");
    return;
}
```

That works fine but only if I click into the field in the combobox. When I dont touch it, the program will start without message box. Whats wrong?

Comment: What's the event that's triggering this code? Is it in Form_Load or  ?

Comment: No. I have put it in where the button is clicked to run the programm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))` or `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please select a value");
   return;           
}
```

Note: SelectedIndex will be set to -1 when SelectedValue is blank ONLY when FormattingEnabled is true. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Check the selected index value of dropdown equals `-1`

```
if (Comboboxid.SelectedIndex == -1){
    MessageBox.Show("Your message.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code should work. Although I will also set SelectedIndex as well......

```
if (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem == null || this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
```

you mean "When I dont touch it, the program will start without message box. Whats wrong?" is there any code related with "touch it"

Comment: I meant I had to click into the field of the Box first.

Comment: where do you initialize the combobox ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Ithink this is the one :

```
 if(comboBox.SelectedItems==null) //or if(comboBox.SelectedItems==-1)
     {
       //show  no item was selected from comboBox 
      }
```

or

```
if(comboBox.SelectedItems.Count==0)
{
//message no items selected 
}
```

Comment: There is no property named SelectedItems for asp combo box .. it has only SelectedItem property.

Answer (score 0):

A ComboBox displays a **text box** combined with a ListBox, which enables the user to select items from the list or **enter a new value**. Conditionally testing SelectedItem or SelectedIndex will not handle the case of the user entering a new value from another input device like a keyboard.  Use string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text) to handle all input/selection cases.

Comment: Quite similar answer was posted before by @free4ride

Comment: @free4ride also gave "if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)" as an option which will not work in keyboard input cases

Answer (score 0):

try this is the :

```
  if ((comboBox.SelectedValue == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox.Text))
                        {
    
    //message no items selected 
                    }
```